# I'm trying to implement a search on my flask app

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I am doing a flask tutorial [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/), and in the end, keep developing section it says to implement a search box that filters the index page by name,after trail and error I came up to displaying the search page, but still I don't get the results back of my search.

Here is my Search HTML:

```html
    <form method="GET" action="{{ url_for('blog.search') }}">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Search by" name="q" value="{{ request.args.get('q', '') }}">
       <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
```

Here is my route

```py
    from flask import request
    @bp.route('/search', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def search():
      db = get_db()
      query = request.args.get('q')
      posts = db.execute(
      "SELECT title, body FROM post WHERE body LIKE ? ",
      ('%'+ query +'%',)).fetchall()
      return render_template('blog/search.html', posts=posts )
```

Here is my search 'blog/search.html' template

```
<ul>
  {% for post in posts %}

  <li> {{ post['title'] }} </li>
  <li> {{ post['body'] }} </li>

  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is there a problem in my route or the sql query?
or is there a better way to implement a search, in flask without any extensions, thanks.

Comment: You can use a debugger, like `pdb` or a builtin debugger of your IDE oder editor. Then you can step through and localize the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but i have never used a debugger for python, i will need to do a separate research on it.

Comment: It is not that hard. VS Code has preconfigured setup for Flask debugging and for pdb have a look at https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/

Comment: i'm already checking on it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.
it was a mistake on my end on the 'blog/search.html' template below is my working code

my route for search:

```
@bp.route('/search', methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
  db = get_db()
  query = request.args.get('q')
  posts = db.execute(
    "select id, title from post where title LIKE ? ",
    ('%'+ query+'%',)
  ).fetchall()
  
  return render_template('blog/search.html', posts=posts)
```

note: this route only checks for the title of my db

my new 'blog/search.html' template:

```
{% if posts %}
    <ul>
      {% for post in posts %}
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('blog.single', id=post['id']) }}">{{ post[1] }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>no entries</p>
{% endif %}
```

note: '{{ url_for... }}' is a link used to look into details of the search

Hope this gets helpful to someone trying to implement a search in [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/) tutorial.
cheers :)